# Access an assigned variable outside of main method

Tags: java

Good time of day, everyone! I'm new here, trying to prepare myself for a course in Java. Right now I was recreating this code written by The Coding Train on YouTube, which models a simple perceptron. I have a separate file, where I feed in the values of inputs (3 numbers), create an object p of class Perceptron and then get p.guess. However, it gives me a result of 0.0 That is possible, since it is a valid output of signum, but not all the time. Here my lack of Java knowledge lets me down. Does guess necessarily recognise the changes made to weights array? I think it just uses the initially created empty array at multiplication... How do I fix this? I call it with the code at the end of the page:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Perceptron {
static double[] weights = new double [3];
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i<weights.length; i++){
            weights[i] = randomNumber(-1, 1);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(weights));
    }
    public static double guess(double[] inputs){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
            sum += weights[i]*inputs[i];
        }
        double myguess = Math.signum(sum);
        return myguess;
    }
    public static double randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        double d = Math.random()*(max - min) + min;
        return d;
    }
}


public class myTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron();
        double inputs[] = {-1, 0.5, -0.5};
        double eval = p.guess(inputs);
        System.out.println(eval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Where did you call guess(double[] inputs) method??

Comment: I edited the question, code at the end calls it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed, zero is extremely unlikely.  The only way I can see this possible is if the inputs you are passing to guess are all zero, perhaps add this to your guess method to check;

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));
```

You can pass some known values in to test it's working the way you want with;

```
public static double guessWithKnownValues () {
    final double[] knownValues = {-0.1d,0.1d,-0.1d};
    final double guess = guess(knownValues);
    System.out.println(guess(knownValues));
    return guess;
}
```

About the weights array - yes, guess will notice updates to this array, references to the weights array in both your main and guess methods point to the same instance of the array.

In response to edit : as you are running the test and the perecptron as separate processes, yes, the weights haven't been initialised - your suspicions are correct. Get rid of the statics and try writing you Percepton class like this and then run your test.

```
public class Perceptron {
    double[] weights = new double [3];

    public Perceptron() {
        for (int i = 0; i<weights.length; i++){
            weights[i] = randomNumber(-1, 1);
        }
    }

    public double guess(double[] inputs){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
            sum += weights[i]*inputs[i];
        }
        double myguess = Math.signum(sum);
        return myguess;
    }

    public double randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        double d = Math.random()*(max - min) + min;
        return d;
    }
}
```